# Input Class undefined, but Input id works

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Not sure why the result is undefined here, when I change the following items, `<input type="text" id="myText"` to `<input type="text" class="myText"` and `document.getElementById("myText")` to `document.getElementsByClassName("myText")`

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_text_value

Comment: Are you sure it is undefined? did you try printing the results from getElementsByClassName in console?

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByClassName() returns a nodeList, so if you want your example to work you must use it like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        First Name: <input type="text" class="myText" value="Mickey">
        <p>Click the button to display the value of the value attribute of the text field.</p>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
        <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
           var x = document.getElementsByClassName("myText");
           document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x[0].value;
        }
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned a link with an example seems

```
document.getElementsByClassName("myText").value;
```

You are not suppose to do like that because the getElememtaByClassName function will return a collection of values not a single value like getElementById.

Get the value by using array index

Look into this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName)